# Display category of event tracking data in GA

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a question, I want to add a new category in event tracking data in GA, I added the script ga.js, And in my js when I press on the button I do :

```
GA._trackEvent('Game','Play',value);
```

I looked in console network of browser, so the script have the state 200 OK,
the properties of this script :

```
utmac   UA-1xxxx-1
utmcs   UTF-8
utmdt   Games
utme    5(Game*Play*Golf)
..............
```

The problem is that the category is not added in the google analytics. I look in the Audience>Cutom>Custom Variables. Can you help me please? What I'm doing wrong? Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing a few things up here.

1. You have added code for event tracking
2. You are talking about checking custom variables (Audience>Cutom>Custom Variables)
3. You talk about categories.

Lets take them one at a time.

**Event tracking:**

[Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) is when a user clicks on a button this is an event you can track the button click in Google Analytics by adding the event tracking tag to the button click

```
<a  onclick="_trackevent('button', 'click', 'linktohome');" href="http://www.home.com">home</a>
```

Google Analytics then should store a hit under `behavior -> events -> overview`

**Custom varables**

[Custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) are name-value pair tags that you can insert in your tracking code in order to refine Google Analytics tracking.

If I have a blog site and I have different authors on my blog site, I might create a custom variable for the author name so that I could track in Google Analytics who the author was for a blog post.

Custom variables must be set up in the Admin section of the Google Analytics website each variable has an index id.

```
_setCustomVar("1", "Author", "Jane Doe");
```

This tag is added at the top of the page along side your normal Google analytics snippet.

Custom variables can be seen `(Audience>Cutom>Custom Variables)`

**Catagorie**

Now Categories associated with the event can be seen at

```
behavior -> events -> overview
```

Update:

The signature of the _trackEvent() method is as follows:

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
```

- category (required) The name you supply for the group of objects you want to track.
- action (required) A **string** that is uniquely paired with each category, and commonly used to define the type of user interaction for the web object.
- opt_label (optional) An optional **string** to provide additional dimensions to the event data.
- opt_value (optional) An **integer** that you can use to provide numerical data about the user event.
- opt_noninteraction (optional) A **boolean** that when set to true, indicates that the event hit will not be used in bounce-rate calculation.

Comment: I make now : `GA._trackEvent('Game','Play','Golf',niveau);` , I look in the GA and the niveau not show, shows only Game,Play,Golf, why?

Comment: if you check the documentation the 4th value sent to _trackEvent  is called opt_value it is an integer you are trying to send text.  try adding the number 1 or something.

Comment: How to send this niveau?

Comment: you cant,   _trackEvent('game','play','golf', 1)  or how about _trackEvent('game','play','golf niveau')

Comment: No, I need to send this niveau as a 4 parameter

Comment: That's nice, but the method does not support that. the 4 item in the method is an integer not a string.  Just because you want to do something doesn't mean that the API supports it.

Comment: you must send a number.   if you can convert niveau to a number that's a prefect solution.

Comment: I tried like this : `GA._trackEvent('Game','Play','Golf',1);` but not work, in the console I view : `(Game*Play*Golf)(1)`

Comment: remember it can take up to 24 hours for data to show up on the website.    check behavior -> events -> overview tomorrow.

Comment: You can also check in real time reports to see the event immediately. Make sure you are not filtering your own visits.

Comment: Thx nyuen, I see the event in real time but I can't send the last value : 1 :(